# Mathematica code for solving MHD viscoelastic fluid flow

Tags: fluid-dynamics

Where might I find Mathematica code for solving MHD viscoelastic fluid flow using Homotopy Analysis method?

Comment: There is also a scientific computing SE: [scicomp.SE].

Answer (score 10):

You might try the [BVPh package](http://numericaltank.sjtu.edu.cn/BVPh2_0.htm) by Yinlong Zhao and Shijun Liao that applies the HAM (Homotopy analysis method) to solve various problems among which that of MHD (Magnetohydrodynamics) viscous flows, if I interpret the presented materials on their web site correctly.

It seems to be reasonably actively developed as the most recent version was released on 18 May 2013

Comment: I was voting to close, but would retract that now in view of your answer.

Comment: @YvesKlett You might consider upvoting as well, otherwise I believe this old question still counts as unanswered.

Comment: If this question is going to stick around, can we get MHD defined for the benefit of those less informed?

Comment: @bob No problem, added explanation in the text.